# Laravel - Select and change all rows that have a certain amount of specific duplicates

Tags: sql, laravel

My website has posts, and posts can have votes. The votes table has the following columns:

- id (primary)
- user_id
- post_id
- ip_address
- invalid (boolean)
- created_at

I want to select all the votes created in the last hour, then out of those I want to get all records that have duplicates in **BOTH** ip_address and user_id, and if there's more than a certain amount, set those votes to invalid = true.

Explanation for clarity: The idea behind this is that I don't want the same person with many accounts voting over and over. But I also realize that 2 or 3 people could share an IP address. But if a post something like 10+ votes from the same IP, that's probably vote manipulation so I set those votes to invalid.

Comment: What have you tried? You could use an update statement that is paired with a where clause powered from a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a raw query [Laravel raw query docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions). To get a list of grouped Ids I would do something like:

```
$query = "select count(id) as count, user_id, ip_address, group_concat(id) as ids from votes group by user_id, ip_address where created_at > '" . Carbon::now()->subHour()->toDateTimeString() . "'"; // Do not forget to import Carbon
```

That would retrieve what you are looking for, then if you would like to invalidate them, you could iterate the rows and explode the ids columns, and do an update query to set the invalid column to true.

```
update votes set invalid = 1 where id in (....)
```

If you do not like raw queries on your controlllers, you could create a query-scope method https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes
and have it looking like `App\Models\Vote::removeDuplicates()` or even `App\Models\Vote::getValidVotes($updateInvalids = true)` and has this last method performing the invalidations logic.

Hope it works.
Cheers

Comment: I've seen similar problems using havingRaw (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw). Would this be applicable here?

Comment: I do not recommend completely raw queries... you are using Laravel, take advantage of Eloquent... I will try to create a query for you, but always try to avoid RAW queries as it is less readable compared to Eloquent...

Comment: @matiaslauriti I originally wanted to do an Eloquent solution but I don't know how

Comment: @FelixMaxime you can use query-scopes to create Eloquent instance or static method, I get u do not want to do a raw query but behind the scenes this is what any ORM does, anyway by using scopes u'll get functionality and readability u're looking for (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#query-scopes)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding a unique to your table can handle the problem of duplicate votes:

```
$table->unique(["post_id", "user_id", "ip_address"]);
```

Or let the person vote only once for a post:

```
$table->unique(["post_id", "user_id"]);
```

Regards

Comment: I'm sorry but you did not correctly understand my post. Users already can't vote on a post more than once. Furthermore, I want the same IP to be able to vote on the same post, but only up to a certain point.